# Get fixed cells in multiple excel to the new one

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new in excel VBA and have a question on fetch data from multiple excel workbook to the noew one.
I will explain here:
1. In a Main Folder (`"C:\desktop\Main\"`), there are multiple sub-folders in it (here I take `folder A1` and `folder A2` as an example). `"C:\desktop\Main\A1\"` & `"C:\desktop\Main\A2\"`
   In each sub-folders, there are multiple excels in it.
   For example: In `folder A1`, there are 2 folders (`A1-2015.xlsx` and `A1-2016.xlsx`) `"C:\desktop\Main\A1\A1-2015.xlsx"` and `"C:\desktop\Main\A1\A1-2016.xlsx"`
In `folder A2`, there are 3 folders (`A2-2015.xlsx`, `A2-2016.xlsx` and `A2-2017.xlsx`)
I want to get cells in these excels into new excel workbook.
2. So, based on the explanation on item1. I take one of A1 (`A1-2016.xlsx`) and one of A2 (`A2-2017.xlsx`) excel for example.
[image: A1]
A1 looks like above.
[image: A2]
A2 contains the same template in the fixed cells with different numbers/characters in it.
3. I want to fetch them like this:
[image: New Excel]
All excels have fixed template like the example above.
How can I do if I have multiple folders with multiple excels in it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether you know how many levels of subfolders you have under the main folder. If this is predictable, e.g. you know there is only ever the following two levels (Main>A1) then it is pretty simple. You want to use File System Objects (will require you to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime from the tools>references menu).

Once you have added that, use the below code to do the work for you (you might need to adjust it slightly as I'm mainly guessing as to what info you want to merge from the files into the main one):

```
Sub Merge_Files()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Main_Fold As Folder, Sub_1 As Folder
    Dim Fil As File
    Dim Main_WB As Workbook, New_WB As Workbook
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
    Set Main_WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Main_Fold = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\Main\") 'Replace this with a reference to your actual main folder.
    For Each Sub_1 In Main_Fold.subFolders
        For Each Fil In Sub_1.Files
            Set New_WB = Workbooks.Open(Fil.Path)
            For X = 2 To 1000
                If Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & X).Value = "" Then
                        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value
                        Exit For
                End If
                If Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value Then Exit For
            Next X
            For Y = 2 To 5
                Main_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(X, Y) = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C" & (Y + 1)).Value
            Next Y
            For Y = 4 To 9
                If Y = 6 Then Y = 7
                If Y < 6 Then
                        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(X, Y + 2) = New_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(9, Y)
                    Else
                        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(X, Y + 1) = New_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(9, Y)
                End If
            Next Y
            Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("K" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("K21").Value
            New_WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next Fil
        Next Sub_1
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code for me because I'm new in VBA. `For X = 2 To 1000` and `For Y = 2 To 5`, I cannot understand clear here.Thank you

Comment: So the code cycles through each sub folder in the Main Folder (which you have to edit the address for) and then cycles through each sub folder of that folder (3 levels in total). It then cycles through each file in those folders (assuming that only excel files are contained within) and then opens each file to copy the requested values (I guessed this based on what you showed on the screen shots). Once it has copied the values across it closes the excel workbook (processed not main) and doesn't save changes (to avoid accidentally changing your original data).

Comment: I would recommend that you copy and paste it into VBA, change the folder location in the line "Set Main_Fold = FSO.GetFolder..."  to your Main Folder and then use the F8 key to step through the code and literally watch what it does...this is the best way to learn how VBA works and what you can do.

Comment: Those specific For X = and Y = lines are stepping through an iterative process. I assumed that you would want to look for the name of the company (A1 for eg) in the list prior to generating a new line for it. So the X For loop looks for a row that has the company in it and then creates one if it doesn't find it. The Y For Loops are merely designed to limit the amount of code required to execute the copying of values.

Comment: I try your code and it doesn'y work. VBA doesn't execute. I edit my question to explain more. Thank you

Comment: I see your problem, so you mean that there is only 1 level of subfolder with Main, and then files in that folder? I will edit the code.

Comment: @PeterChen if the adjusted code doesn’t work, then post a comment about what specific error you get, or contact me via a chat session

Comment: Great. It works. (1) If I want to know each row of data belongs to which year, How can I do? (2) I step through your code, but still cannot understad clear after the code `For X = 2 To 1000` and `For Y = 4 To 9`. Could you please explain more clear in the answer above? Thank you

Comment: @PeterChen sorry, but you should do some research online and see if you can develop what I have provided to get the end result you require. There are plenty of resources out there. Alternatively go to a freelancer website and hire someone to develop code for you. What I’ve provided IS a solution to the question you posted!